# Anonymous C# delegate within a loop

Tags: c#, delegates

Hi all I am trying to write and anonymous delegate. as the integer variable is shared among the delegate I need it to be the local instance of every delegate such that `rs[0]` always gets `nics[0]`, `rs[1]` always gets `nics[1]` and so on... how will I achieve this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nics.Count; i++)
{
    rs[i] = new RollingSeries(monitor, new RollingSeries.NextValueDelegate(delegate()
    {
        return GetNetworkUtilization(nics[i]);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Be *extremely* careful about what you ask for. Do you want your first closure to always get the value in nics[0] *at the time the delegate is invoked*, or do you want the closure to get the value that happened to be in nics[0] *at the time the delegate was created*? Those are two different things; nics[0] is a variable, so its value can change over time. Do you want the closure to see that change, or ignore that change?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make a local copy of `i`:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < nics.Count; i++)
   {
         int j = i;
         rs[i] = new RollingSeries(monitor, new RollingSeries.NextValueDelegate(delegate()
         {
            return GetNetworkUtilization(nics[j]);
          }));
    }
```

[The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Comment: Or an local copy of the item in the array.

Answer (score 6):

Use a local to get a different value per iteration

```
for (int i = 0; i < nics.Count; i++)
   {
         int localI = i;
         rs[i] = new RollingSeries(monitor, new RollingSeries.NextValueDelegate(delegate()
         {
            return GetNetworkUtilization(nics[localI]);
          }));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Put `int j = i` inside your loop and refer to `j` within the lambda expression.

If you are curious about why this happens, here is an MSDN blog entry containing a detailed technical explanation: [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)